# Python. Get peer cert if verify_mode is CERT_NONE

Tags: python-3.x, ssl-certificate, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to get client certificate on aiohttp server, but it returns None.

`crt=request.transport.get_extra_info('ssl_object').getpeercert(True)`  
Here crt will be **None** !

But if I set verify_mode to CERT_REUIRED it's working.

But I also want to get client certificate even if it no valid.

How can I do it ?

I just need to read Subject Key Identifier from client.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.